# JavaScript video: Function Only works when button is clicked twice quickly

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, web-mediarecorder

I have the below code meant to record a video for exactly 2 seconds and then play to the end user. After recording the video, the video fails to load in the player. However if I click on **start recording** twice quickly, it works perfectly fine:

### Code Snippet

```
function startRecording() {
  recordedChunks = [];
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
  window.mediaRecorder = mediaRecorder;
  mediaRecorder.start();

  setTimeout(() => {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
      // Push the recorded media data to
      // the chunks array
      recordedChunks.push(e.data);
    };
    const recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/mp4" });
    const recordedUrl = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
    window.recordedUrl = recordedUrl;
    recordingSection.style.display = "none";
    reviewSection.style.display = "flex";
    reviewVideoPlayer.src = recordedUrl;
    reviewVideoPlayer.play();
  }, 2000);
}

function approveRecording() {
  reviewSection.style.display = "flex";
  recordingSection.style.display = "none";
  reviewVideoPlayer.pause();
  reviewVideoPlayer.currentTime = 0;
  reviewVideoPlayer.play();
}

function recordAgain() {
  reviewSection.style.display = "none";
  recordingSection.style.display = "flex";
  reviewVideoPlayer.pause();
  reviewVideoPlayer.currentTime = 0;
  startRecording();
}

startRecordingButton.addEventListener("click", startRecording);
approveButton.addEventListener("click", approveRecording);
recordAgainButton.addEventListener("click", recordAgain);
```

I am new to `JavaScript` and I need it only for this part

Answer (score 2):

@FayezAbulenein I believe you are missing the piece of code which [reloads the video element with the newly changed source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_load.asp). Update the block where you set the video src to this and give it a try:

**from**

```js
reviewVideoPlayer.src = recordedUrl;
reviewVideoPlayer.play();
```

**to**

```js
reviewVideoPlayer.src = recordedUrl;
reviewVideoPlayer.load();
reviewVideoPlayer.play();
```

Comment: thanks but I I tried it it did not work